# Remove blank line at end of SSRS CSV report when excelmode=false is alredy set

Tags: reporting-services, export-to-csv

I am trying to export a report from SSRS into CSV and just have no data rows or blank lines at the end.

I have already added the following to the config file:

```
<Extension Name="CSV (No Header)" Type="Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.DataRenderer.CsvReport,Microsoft.ReportingServices.DataRendering">
    <OverrideNames>
       <Name Language="en-us"> CSV No Header</Name>
    </OverrideNames>
    <Configuration>
       <DeviceInfo>
          <NoHeader>true</NoHeader>
          <ExcelMode>False</ExcelMode>
       </DeviceInfo>
    </Configuration>
</Extension>
```

The header section works, but only one of the two blank lines is removed. how do i remove the other blank line?

Thanks